# HP 4015 printer randomly printing blank pages?

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have an [HP4015n](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3558794&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3558793) printer (networked) which has been working great for about a year.  Recently, we've noticed that the printer will occasionally print a blank page in place of an order.  So, lets say we're printing 50 orders (each an individual print job) - it will randomly replace maybe 2 orders with a blank page.

I'm at a total loss of how to troubleshoot this. Ideas?

Comment: Are you using PCL6 drivers for it? Are they the latest version? It's certainly worth trying that first...

Comment: Using the latest PCL6.  Just upgraded printer firmware this morning as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step would be to check that the output from your software is not what is causing the issue.

I would download software like [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to first try printing to PDF to ensure the software is not the one producing blank pages (after a software update, for example)

Second step would be to elimate the networking aspect and try a locally connected (USB) printer.

If neither of the above helps, driver updates for the print driver or new toner (if laser printer) or new cartridge for inkjet.

Comment: We did batch ~270 orders in a single PDF and it all printed without incident. Updated the PCL6 drivers and also the printer firmware this morning.  Also rebooted Windows Server 2008 which was acting as the print server.  We'll see if any of these resolve it.  Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: If this persists after your troubleshooting it's probably best asking this question to be moved to serverfault. As an aside what ERP software are you using? Have you spoken/contacted their technical support?